# Automatic texture atlas with separated object UVs

Tags: texturing, uv

Using the bundled texture atlas plugin I can automatically unwrap multiple objects onto one atlas. However, when I do so, faces from one object land all over the map and are mingled with faces from other objects. What I would prefer to have is to have each object occupy its own box inside the atlas - as if I had unwrapped each object by itself and then scaled and moved each of the UVs of the object manually so that they fit next to each other on the atlas. Is there a way to automate this process other than writing code?

Comment: I can highly recommend [Multi Object UV Editing](https://github.com/ndee85/Multi-Object-UV-Editing).

Comment: From the video on the linked page it seems that Multi Object UV Editing cannot do what I ask -- it merely creates intermingled layouts just like Texture Atlas.